# How to call suspend function in gradle task?

Tags: gradle, kotlin-coroutines, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've tried following code, but the task finishes before response arrives:

```kotlin
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.6.5")
        classpath("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:1.6.5")
    }
}

tasks {
    register("suspendCall") {
        doLast {
            kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope.launch {
                val client = io.ktor.client.HttpClient()
                val response = client.get<io.ktor.client.statement.HttpResponse>("https://ktor.io/")
                println(response)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a correct way to wait for async code to complete?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, to work asynchronously or in parallel, you will want to use the [Worker API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/worker_api.html):

> The Worker API provides the ability to break up the execution of a task action into discrete units of work and then to execute that work concurrently and asynchronously. This allows Gradle to fully utilize the resources available and complete builds faster.

As a result, you should not need to use a specific language asynchronous concept such as Kotlin's coroutines. Instead, you can use plain Kotlin or Java, and let Gradle handle the asynchronous bits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Worker API definitely can solve the task. But is there a way to use WorkerExecutor as coroutine context? It would be much easier to describe the task in build.gradle.kts script instead of buildSrc with all of those injected parameters.

Comment: @Nolequen you might be able to create your own dispatcher that is wired to the Worker API https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-dispatcher/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way is to wrap the call into [`suspendBlocking`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html).

The following works for me:

```kotlin
import io.ktor.client.request.get

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.6.5")
        classpath("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:1.6.5")
    }
}

tasks {
    register("suspendCall") {
        doLast {
            kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking {
                val client = io.ktor.client.HttpClient()
                val response = client.get<io.ktor.client.statement.HttpResponse>("https://ktor.io/")
                println(response)
            }
        }
    }
}
```